# get fbml comments to automatically show form

Tags: facebook, comments, fbml

I'm writing facebook app in fbml (not in iframe).

I added comments with `<fb:comments ...>` and it appears to work. 
However, to add a comment, user has to click `Add a comment...` link to see the textarea and post button.

I am wondering is there a way to automatically show the form?
I want it to really look like here:

[developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments)

(with or without the like button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well... to answer my own question:

it's documented at

[developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments)

The `showform` parameter.

Maybe it will help someone.